# Equivalence of $L^p$ norm in a bounded domain

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory

For $1<p<q<\infty$ and a bounded domain $\Omega \subseteq \mathbb R^2$, is the following true? $$C_1\Vert f \Vert_{L^{p}(\Omega)} \leq \Vert f \Vert_{L^{q}(\Omega)}\leq C_2\Vert f \Vert_{L^{p}(\Omega)}  $$
The first inequality is easy by simply using the Holder inequality and $C_1$ depends on the finite measure of $\Omega$. How to show the second inequality?

Comment: What are the roles of $p$ and $q$ in the question?

Comment: @UmbertoP. Sorry for the typo. 1 and 2 should be p and q.

Comment: When your domain has finite total measure (whether bounded or not), then you have ONE of your inequalities, but not the other.  When your domain has infinite total measure, then you have neither of the inequalities.

Comment: @GEdgar Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is simply untrue. Let $\Omega$ be any bounded open set containing the origin and let $f(x) = \dfrac 1{|x|^{2/q}}$.